# How to get nearby Locations based on Distance without UI block

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, mapkit

I have longitude and latitude coming from server which are saved in db using core data. when i click on a location in map view I want to display near locations where distance = 100m. How to proceed with this problem? any Suggestions?

What i have tried is , after clicking on a location calculated distance but my UI is blocked. Any Help?

Comment: Using background fetch?

Comment: Can you elaborate more..

Comment: Well, I guess you're fetching into CoreData in main thread, thread that manage the UI. So you can't "update" (which explained its blocked state) UI. So a way to do it, it's to fetch in a background thread. There should be plenty of examples in SO.